# Outlook VBA macro for multiple file attachment according to filename string

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a working macro for Outlook wherein it will create new email. 
However, I need some several files that are needed to be attached from a specific local folder and the files attached always has current date on the file naming (FILE1_ddmmyyyy).
Example: FILE1_30102018.xlsx, FILE2_30102018.xlsx

Below is the code I have right now and I can't figure out how to auto-attach the files with the filename "*30102018.xlsx"

```
Sub FileDraft()

    Dim obApp As Object
    Dim NewMail As MailItem

    'Format(Date, "ddmmyyyy")
    Dim szTodayDate As String
        szTodayDate = Date
    Dim szNextDate As String
    Dim LWeekday As Integer
        LWeekday = Weekday(szTodayDate, vbSunday)

        If LWeekday = "5" Then
            szNextDate = DateAdd("d", 3, szTodayDate)
        Else
            szNextDate = DateAdd("d", 1, szTodayDate)
        End If
        Dim szNextDatereformat As String
            szNextDatereformat = Format(szNextDate, "ddmmyyyy")

    Set obApp = Outlook.Application
    Set NewMail = obApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    'You can change the concrete info as per your needs
    With NewMail
         .Subject = "FILES_" & szNextDatereformat
         .To = "Recipient_Address"
         .CC = "contacts_on_the_CC"
         .Body = "messageBodyhere"
         .Attachments.Add ("C:\Attachments\FILE1_30102018.xlsx")
         .Importance = olImportanceHigh
         .Display
    End With

    Set obApp = Nothing
    Set NewMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: On the other hand, if possible, maybe a dialog box for browsing/inserting attachment may work however I tried to search on the net regarding this, it seems there's no option in macro to do this? I am not sure on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a list of files in `VBA` using wildcards, you can use the `Dir` command.

When calling `Dir` with a parameter, a new search will start, using the parameter as file name pattern (very similar to issuing a `Dir` at the command prompt). It returns the name of a file that matches the name (without the path).

When calling `Dir` without parameter, it will continue the search and return the next file. When no (more) files are found, the empty string is returned.

So, change your code like

```
Const path = "C:\Attachments\"

With NewMail 
    ...
    dim pattern As String, fileName As String
    pattern = path & "*" & szNextDatereformat & ".*"

    fileName = Dir(pattern)
    Do While fileName <> ""
        .Attachments.Add path & fileName 
        fileName = Dir
    Loop
    ...
end With
```

Comment: Thank you so much FunThomas! Your solution worked flawlessly! :) This is nice to know. Cheers mate!